# How Socket Handles more than one simultaneous client requests?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have very basic doubt in Socket programming (somewhat related to networking as well).
I have ServerSocket something like..

```
 ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
```

and I have Socket called incomingLink to handle incoming request..

```
 Socket incomingLink = ss.accept();
```

And note that there are more than 1 client(say 3 clients) having their outgoingLink Socket something like..

```
 Socket outgoingLink = new Socket(ServerIp, 1234);
```

Well, The requirement is that server has some local parameters (say)

```
 String state;
 int timeStamp;
```

which should be updated whenever first client request is arrived. And subsequent requests are discarded. That means if client-1's request is received first, then client-2 and 3's request will be discarded.

Now my question is if all the three client sends their request at exactly the same time, so how my ServerSocket will handle those request ?
Do I need to create an array of socket to handle these three request independently like this ?

```
 Socket[] incomingLink = new Socket[3];
 incomingLink[0] = ss.accept();
 incomingLink[1] = ss.accept();
 incomingLink[2] = ss.accept();
```

Or else if I use a single incomingLink socket, Will the underlying transport protocol(TCP/UDP) do the work for me to handle these simultaneous requests by buffering them to buffer, and maintaining a proper order and then supply them one after another to my ServerSocket, so that my single incomingLink Socket will handle them properly ?
(Assuming that variation in propagation delays of these three request can be there even if these are sent at the same time).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to create one thread for each request.

Example :
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109654/creating-a-socket-server-which-allows-multiple-connections-via-threads-and-java>

Answer (score 2):

Usually you create client Sockets listening in the loop, something like this:

```
while(shouldAcceptConnections){

Socket client = ss.accept();

// usually here you would fire a thread to handle your client

}
```

In other words if you do ss.accept() not in the loop but only once and then terminate only the first client will manage to connect (others will be rejected- passively as there will be no accepting.). You can of course also do this in the loop and reject them actively.

Comment: If Transport protocol does the job for me of maintaining a proper buffering order, so if I put my listening socket in loop, it will handle the requests in proper order only. I need not care even if simultaneous requests are coming. Right? Please correct me.

Comment: Yes the client request will be in order

Answer (score 0):

This is a ***very*** strange requirement. Are you sure you've understood it correctly?

> if all the three client sends their request at exactly the same time

There's no such thing as 'exactly the same time' in a network. (a) It is undiscoverable, and (b) the network is a sequential mediuem. So the connect requests will arrive in a sequence, not simultaneously. To be specific, `accept()` will return one `Socket` at a time, in whatever order your local TCP stack decides is appropriate.

> Do I need to create an array of socket to handle these three request independently

I don't see why. You just need to create `Socket` variables to store the result of each `accept()`, and handle each `Socket` in a separate thread.

> If I use a single incomingLink socket

You can't. The suggestion doesn't make sense. Each accepted `Socket` is a separate object.

> Will the underlying transport protocol(TCP/UDP) do the work for me to handle these simultaneous requests by buffering them to buffer, and maintaining a proper order and then supply them one after another to my ServerSocket

Yes, see above.

> so that my single incomingLink Socket will handle them properly?

I don't know what this means.

Comment: I mean Will the single incomingLink socket `incomingLink = ss.accept();` object be sufficient to handle all those requests?

Comment: But now as you said that Transport protocol will do the job for me of maintaining a proper buffering order, so if I put my listening socket in loop, it will handle the requests in proper order only. Right?

Comment: Given what I've already said, the question is either redundant or doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well I like your solution and suggestions which you've given above. And I was just trying to get more knowledge from you but you are saying that "question doesn't make sense". I think people may ask any question, Stackoverflow says that people like you should properly guide them. Well Thanks for the answer. I should follow it.

Comment: I'm not in a position to know what it is that you don't understand. I told you above that there *isn't* a 'single incomingLink socket': there is a new Socket per accept(). You seem to be asking me to just repeat myself.