# Java server not closing properly?

Tags: java, sockets

I've tried everything, and I'm at wit's end.  I'm writing a simple file server that will let the user telnet in, supply a username and search for the access level given to that user, and then show a list of files and only allow them to see the contents of the file if they have a sufficient access level. This code is for the server side, I'm just using PuTTY for the client.

The first run works as expected,

```
What is your username? paul

Filename:Access Level
chemistryhomework.txt:5
messageforbob.txt:0
nuclearlaunchcodes.txt:10
Which file would you like to read?
nuclearlaunchcodes.txt
The launch password is "UnlimitedBreadsticks"
```

Then I close PuTTY and try a second time, and get this

```
Filename:Access Level
chemistryhomework.txt:5
messageforbob.txt:0
nuclearlaunchcodes.txt:10
Which file would you like to read?
```

When it should start back from the beginning and ask me for my username.  The third attempt, it shows a blank line and disconnects after a few seconds.

The file containing all of the filenames and their access levels looks like this:

```
chemistryhomework.txt:5
nuclearlaunchcodes.txt:10
messageforbob.txt:0
```

I think it may be somewhere in here

```
//show list of files
int fileaccess;
outToClient.writeBytes("\n\rFilename:Access Level \n \r");
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : files.entrySet()) //show all files and access levels
{
      String key = entry.getKey();
      Integer value = entry.getValue();
      outToClient.writeBytes(key + ":" + value + "\n \r");
}
while(!check)
{   
//ask user for file to read
outToClient.writeBytes("Which file would you like to read? \n \r");
String filetoread = inFromClient.readLine();
try
{
fileaccess = files.get(filetoread); //get access level requirement of file
    if (fileaccess > accesslevel) //if user is lacking the access level
    {
        outToClient.writeBytes("Error: You do not have sufficient privileges to access this file! \n \r");
        welcomeSocket.close();
        connectionSocket.close();
    }
    else
    {
        try //try to read the file, if it exists. Just a backup verification
        {
            file = new File(filetoread);
            Scanner scannerfile = new Scanner(file);
            while (scannerfile.hasNextLine()) 
                    {
                        String line = scannerfile.nextLine();
                        line=line.trim();
                        outToClient.writeBytes(line + "\n\r");
                    }
            outToClient.writeBytes("\n\r");
                    scannerfile.close();
        } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
           outToClient.writeBytes("File not found! \n \r");
    }
    check = true;
    }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) //first line of defense for checking made-up files
{
    outToClient.writeBytes("Error: File does not exist! \n \r");
}
}
check = true;
//outToClient.writeBytes("Press enter to terminate session"); //user can see contents of file just in case disconnecting
//inFromClient.readLine();                                    //closes the window (like PuTTY)
inFromClient.close();
outToClient.close();
welcomeSocket.close();
connectionSocket.close();
```

But here is my code, in its entirety.  I left in a bunch of attempts in vain to fix it by closing everything.

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Server 
{
static Map<String, Integer> files = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //contains file names and the access level required to open them
static Map<String, Integer> users = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //contains user names and the access level assigned to them

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    out.println("Starting server...");

    //read datafile.txt into files hashmap
    File file = new File("datafile.txt");
    try
    {
        out.println("Reading datafile.txt");
        Scanner scannerdata = new Scanner(file);

        while (scannerdata.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            String line = scannerdata.nextLine();
            line.trim();
            String field[] = line.split(":");

            files.put(field[0], Integer.parseInt(field[1]));
        }
        scannerdata.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        out.println("datafile.txt not found!");
    }
    ////////debug////////////
    //for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : files.entrySet()) 
    //{
    //  String key = entry.getKey();
    //  Integer value = entry.getValue();

    //  out.println(key);
    //  out.println(value);
    //}
    //int debugclearance = files.get("nuclearlaunchcodes.txt");
    //out.println(debugclearance);
    ////////debug////////////

    //read userfile.txt into users hashmap
    file = new File("userfile.txt");
    try
    {
        out.println("Reading userfile.txt");
        Scanner scannerusers = new Scanner(file);

        while (scannerusers.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            String line = scannerusers.nextLine();
            line.trim();
            String field[] = line.split(":");

            users.put(field[0], Integer.parseInt(field[1]));
        }
        scannerusers.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        out.println("userfile.txt not found!");
    }
    ////////debug////////////
    //for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : users.entrySet()) 
    //{
    //  String key = entry.getKey();
    //  Integer value = entry.getValue();

    //  out.println(key);
    //  out.println(value);
    //}
    //int debugclearance = users.get("paul");
    //out.println(debugclearance);
    ////////debug////////////

    String clientinput;
    boolean check = false;
    int accesslevel = 0;        

    while(true)
    {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
        Socket connectionSocket = null;
        BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
        DataOutputStream outToClient = null;

        try
        {
            //start connection
            //ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(19000);
            //Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(19000);
            connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            //BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            //DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());


            while(!check) //authenticate user
            {
                outToClient.writeBytes("What is your username?");
                outToClient.writeBytes(" ");
                String username = inFromClient.readLine();

                //alternate method I tried
                //if(users.get(username) == null)
                //{
                //  outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid username");
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //  check = true;
                //}

                try
                {
                    accesslevel = users.get(username);
                    check = true;
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    outToClient.writeBytes("Incorrect username \n \r");
                    welcomeSocket.close();
                    connectionSocket.close();
                }
            }

            check = false;

            //debug
            //outToClient.writeBytes("It worked!");
            //outToClient.writeBytes(clientinput);

            //show list of files
            int fileaccess;
            outToClient.writeBytes("\n\rFilename:Access Level \n \r");
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : files.entrySet()) //show all files and access levels
            {
              String key = entry.getKey();
              Integer value = entry.getValue();
              outToClient.writeBytes(key + ":" + value + "\n \r");
            }
            while(!check)
            {   
                //ask user for file to read
                outToClient.writeBytes("Which file would you like to read? \n \r");
                String filetoread = inFromClient.readLine();
                try
                {
                    fileaccess = files.get(filetoread); //get access level requirement of file
                    if (fileaccess > accesslevel) //if user is lacking the access level
                    {
                        outToClient.writeBytes("Error: You do not have sufficient privileges to access this file! \n \r");
                        welcomeSocket.close();
                        connectionSocket.close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try //try to read the file, if it exists. Just a backup verification
                        {
                            file = new File(filetoread);
                            Scanner scannerfile = new Scanner(file);
                            while (scannerfile.hasNextLine()) 
                            {
                                String line = scannerfile.nextLine();
                                line=line.trim();
                                outToClient.writeBytes(line + "\n\r");
                            }
                            outToClient.writeBytes("\n\r");
                            scannerfile.close();
                        } 
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                        {
                            outToClient.writeBytes("File not found! \n \r");
                        }
                        check = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) //first line of defense for checking made-up files
                {
                    outToClient.writeBytes("Error: File does not exist! \n \r");
                }
            }
            check = true;
            //outToClient.writeBytes("Press enter to terminate session"); //user can see contents of file just in case disconnecting
            //inFromClient.readLine();                                    //closes the window (like PuTTY)
            inFromClient.close();
            outToClient.close();
            welcomeSocket.close();
            connectionSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            //out.println("Connection to client lost");
            inFromClient.close();
            outToClient.close();
            welcomeSocket.close();
            connectionSocket.close();
        }
        inFromClient.close();
        outToClient.close();
        welcomeSocket.close();
        connectionSocket.close();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you keep using the same socket. Also I think that you would like to support multiple connections with multi threading. Maybe you can look at this answer?

[Creating a socket server which allows multiple connections via threads and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109654/creating-a-socket-server-which-allows-multiple-connections-via-threads-and-java)

I think that it will put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are mismanaging the variable 'check'.  You are setting it to true to exit the loop, and also to skip the authentication process.  Try using two different variables for these part to avoid this type of confusion.