# Streaming using spring tcp connection factory

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, integration

I have a following use case:

- server listens on a specific port for new socket connections
- client opens a server socket connection and starts streaming the input stream
- server accepts the connection and does something in real time with the input stream

I have implemented it using Spring Boot (deploying on tomcat) for a single socket using the following code:

```
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6666)) {
        if (serverSocket.isBound()) {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            doSomething(client.getInputStream());               
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to be able to handle multiple client connections in a clean way. I thought I could use Spring Integration's TCP connection factory for that job but I think I totally missed the messaging part and because in my use case I'm not sending any messages but a plain stream this won't work, right? With this setup I was getting hundreds of messages from the client instead of one stream:

```
@Bean
public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverCF() {
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(port);
    connFactory.setDeserializer(new SpeechSocketDeserializer());
    connFactory.setSingleUse(true);
    return connFactory;
}

@Bean
public TcpInboundGateway tcpInGate(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    TcpInboundGateway inGate = new TcpInboundGateway();
    inGate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    inGate.setRequestChannel(fromTcp());
    return inGate;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Could you please suggest what would be the best way to implement handling of multiple socket connections on the server side? Can I use some of the Spring abilities / frameworks?

Comment: You might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109654/creating-a-socket-server-which-allows-multiple-connections-via-threads-and-java